# Flutter Rebuild widget to get translated version after language change

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-getx

```
class OnboardingSelectLanguagePageController extends GetxController {
  RxString languageSelected = "".obs;
  bool isOnboardingPage = true;
  List<String> languagesList = [];
  RxBool isSaving = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    if (Get.arguments != null) {
      isOnboardingPage = (Get.arguments);
    }

    if (isOnboardingPage) {
      languagesList = ["English", "Hinglish"];
    } else {
      languagesList = [
        "English",
        "Hinglish",
        "Odia",
        "Bengali",
        "Telugu",
        "Malayalam",
        "Hindi",
        "Punjabi"
      ];
    }
  }

  Future<void> saveLanguage() async {
    isSaving(true);
    final res = await AccountProfileRepository.setAppLanguage(
      language: languageSelected.value,
    );
    isSaving(false);
    if (res.apiFailure != null) {
      showCustomSnackbar(
          res.apiFailure!.errorMessage!, res.apiFailure!.errorResponse!,
          isError: true);
    } else {
      if (isOnboardingPage) {
        Get.offNamed(Routes.ONBOARDING_LOGIN_PAGE);
      } else {
        Get.back();
      }
      showCustomSnackbar("Success", "Langauage changed successfully");
    }
  }
  Future<void>changeAppLanguage({required PreferredLanguageMapping preferredLanguageListIndex})async {
    showPrint("hello");
    changeLanguageAndStoreInLocalDb(
        preferredLanguageMapping: PreferredLanguageMapping(
          languageId: preferredLanguageListIndex.languageId, languageName: preferredLanguageListIndex.languageName, languageCode: preferredLanguageListIndex.languageCode, countryCode: preferredLanguageListIndex.countryCode,
        )
    );
    // Get.offNamed(Routes.ONBOARDING_LOGIN_PAGE);

  }
}
```

and my view is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/components/bottom_sheet/bottom_sheet_button.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/components/buttons/select_tile_button.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/components/text/custom_text.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/components/widgets/custom_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/utils/constants.dart';

import '../../../../helpers/custom_messages.dart';
import '../../../../localization/preferred_language_mapping.dart';
import '../../../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../controllers/onboarding_select_language_page_controller.dart';

class OnboardingSelectLanguagePageView
    extends GetView<OnboardingSelectLanguagePageController> {
  const OnboardingSelectLanguagePageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
          !controller.isOnboardingPage ? customAppBar(title: "Language") : null,
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    16, controller.isOnboardingPage ? 34 : 20, 22.81, 30),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Select your Preferred\nApp language",
                          style: CustomTextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: Constants.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/Aor3.png",
                          height: 70,
                          width: 66.5,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 31),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: preferredLanguageList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        // final language = controller.languagesList[index];

                        final language = preferredLanguageList[index].languageName;
                        return Obx(
                              () => GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              controller.languageSelected(language);
                            },
                            child: SelectTileButton(
                              text: language,
                              isSelected:
                              controller.languageSelected.value == language,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 80)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Obx(
        () => BottomSheetButton(
          isEnabled: controller.languageSelected.value.isNotEmpty,
          text: controller.isOnboardingPage ? "Proceed" : "Save",
          isLoading: controller.isSaving.value,
          onTap: () {
            controller.saveLanguage().then((value) {
              final selectedLanguageIndex = preferredLanguageList.indexWhere((element) =>
              element.languageName == controller.languageSelected.value
              );
              if (selectedLanguageIndex != -1) {
                controller.changeAppLanguage(preferredLanguageListIndex: preferredLanguageList[selectedLanguageIndex]).then((value) {
                });
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my account setting tile code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/components/text/custom_text.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:xxx/app/utils/image_path.dart';

class AccountSettingsTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final AccountSettingModel accountSettingsModel;
  const AccountSettingsTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.accountSettingsModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        accountSettingsModel.onTap();
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Kolors.seperatorLight,
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Kolors.boxShadowColor.withOpacity(0.07),
              spreadRadius: 0,
              blurRadius: 8,
              offset: const Offset(0, 2),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              accountSettingsModel.icon,
              height: 24,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                accountSettingsModel.text,
                style: CustomTextStyle(
                  color: Kolors.primarycolor,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: Constants.medium,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (accountSettingsModel.isTrailingIcon)
              Image.asset(
                ImagePath.icArRight,
                height: 20,
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AccountSettingModel {
  final Function onTap;
  final String text;
  final String icon;
  final bool isTrailingIcon;
  AccountSettingModel({
    required this.onTap,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    this.isTrailingIcon = true,
  });
}
```

i am able to chaange app language but to see it working i have to navigate back to account setting page so that it can rebuilt and display current language. after changing the language i need to navigate back to account setting and its tile should now visible in new selected language, but its now, if i go back to dashboard and come back to settings its working fine

im new to flutter